# How to get coordinates on double click on Openstreetmap?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I am using [angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) , I want to get coordinates of the point where I double click.

A similar question:

[Convert point to lat lon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967638/convert-point-to-lat-lon)

But I want to use it in angularjs.

Comment: You mean, getting coordinates using directive which you are using?

Comment: Yes, using  angular-openlayers-directive !

Answer (score 0):

You should check this example out: http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/080-events-propagation-example.html. It shows how you can find the lat-long coordinates for mouseover. Also, here is a fiddle I made showing how you can extend it for double click: http://jsfiddle.net/anushamc/6q2az5xz/. Briefly, you need to listen for the events on the map by including it in the defaults like:

```
defaults: {
      events: {
        map: ['singleclick', 'pointermove', 'dblclick']
      }
    }
```

and

```
<openlayers ol-defaults="defaults"></openlayers>
```

and include a listener for openlayers.map.dblclick on the scope.

```
$scope.$on('openlayers.map.dblclick', function(event, data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      if ($scope.projection === data.projection) {
        $scope.mousedoubleclickposition = data.coord;
      } else {
        var p = ol.proj.transform([data.coord[0], data.coord[1]], data.projection, $scope.projection);
        $scope.mousedoubleclickposition = {
          lat: p[1],
          lon: p[0],
          projection: $scope.projection
        }
      }
    });
  });
```